# Scrollbar shows under overflow hidden if element has children with relative position (Google Chrome - Mac OS)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have two divs that have horizontal scroll.

I want to hide the scrollbar and to do that, I've made the parent a little bit smaller in height and added overflow hidden.

This works in most cases, but if in one of the scrolling divs I have an element that has position relative, it shows the scrollbar.

If you don't have a horizontal scroll mouse or trackpad please I created a gif here: http://recordit.co/PZeqITL3aA

The code is also on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anything/pen/yqNzLR?editors=1100

Also, I am open to any alternative of hiding the scroll with this HTML structure, but I need the pozition relative to the last elements since there I want to add some drop downs that are absolutely positioned and flow above.

This happens only on Google Chrome on Mac and maybe Android devices.

Thanks!

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.overflow__wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.overflow__content {
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.overflow--1 {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.2);
  /*
    * If I add position relative to any of the child elements, the scroll will be visible. WTF?
    */
}
.overflow--1 button {
  position: relative;
}
.overflow--2 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
.overflow button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="overflow overflow--1">
    <div class="overflow__wrap">
      <div class="overflow__content">
        <button>Scroll horizontally</button>
        <button>Horizontal scroll visible under</button>
        <button>Horizontal scroll visible under</button>
        <button>Horizontal scroll visible under</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overflow overflow--2">
    <div class="overflow__wrap">
      <div class="overflow__content">
        <button>Horizontal scroll hidden</button>
        <button>Yes, really</button>
        <button>Yes, really</button>
        <button>Yes, really</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<p>Snippet end</p>
```

**If you want to see this here with "Run snippet" make sure you scroll vertically a bit because the iframe cuts the scrollbars.**

Comment: Why do you need `position: relative` on `overflow`? W/o it (or set to `static`) the scrollbar is hidden.

Comment: @extempl --- The buttons in the code snippet there will be proper divs in my real project and contain some other elements in there like drop-downs that are absolutely positioned relative to the buttons/divs

Comment: That's ok. Just keep `relative`s in `button`s and remove ones from the `.overflow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the `overflow`s `relative` position and keep it for `button` elements (divs in the future). Then the scrollbar will disappear and you will be able to use any nested blocks positioning related to each of the list items (currently, `button` elements).

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow {
  width: 50%;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.overflow__wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.overflow__content {
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.overflow--1 {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.2);
  /*
    * If I add position relative to any of the child elements, the scroll will be visible. WTF?
    */
}
.overflow--1 button {
  position: relative;
}
.overflow--2 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
.overflow button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 160px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="overflow overflow--1">
    <div class="overflow__wrap">
      <div class="overflow__content">
        <button>Scroll horizontally</button>
        <button>Horizontal scroll visible under</button>
        <button>Horizontal scroll visible under</button>
        <button>Horizontal scroll visible under</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overflow overflow--2">
    <div class="overflow__wrap">
      <div class="overflow__content">
        <button>Horizontal scroll hidden</button>
        <button>Yes, really</button>
        <button>Yes, really</button>
        <button>Yes, really</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<p>Snippet end</p>
```